# How to make links as horizontal blocks?

Tags: html, css

So I have a list, but I want them to act as "blocks" so the whole thing is clickable and the background changes color. But I can not have both inline and block as display in css. How do I fix this?

The links at the top.

http://serenex.hostzi.com/

HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
<title>Serenex - Index</title>
<head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="top"> 
<div id="logo">
<a href="http://www.http://serenex.hostzi.com/"> <img src="images/logo1.png" border="0" /> 
</a></div> 
<div id="inbar">
<ul id="topbar">
<li><a href="default.asp"  style="text-decoration: none">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp"  style="text-decoration: none">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp"  style="text-decoration: none">Play</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp"  style="text-decoration: none">Vote</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp"  style="text-decoration: none">Forums</a></li>
</ul> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div id="midsection">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body{
background:#363636;
}

#wrapper{
width:900px;
height:2000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#top{
width:100%
height:150px;
background:white;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#inbar{
height:30px;
width:100%;
background:#dedede;
border-top: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}


#topbar{
position:relative;
top:-10px;
margin-left:-35px;
}

#topbar{
display: block;
}

#topbar li{
display:inline;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-top:6px;
}

#topbar li a{
color:#363636;
display:block;
font: bold 14px arial, sans-serif;
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `padding` to the anchor `a` not the list item `li`. And it has to have the `display: block`.
This would cause it to jumb to a new line, which is why we use `float: left` on the list-item `li` and not `display: inline`.

```
#topbar li{
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#topbar li a{
    color:#363636;
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 20px 5px 6px;
    font: bold 14px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: 1+ This will work. Thanks for not suggesting to wrap the `li` with `a`

Comment: @joshC :) hope you know that LI inside A is **invalid markup**

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I realize that.. that's why I said "thanks for not suggesting to wrap the `li` with `a`"....

Comment: @JoshC heheeh than +100 for you funny sarcasm :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it wasn't sarcasm.

Comment: Well, it almost wasn't, HTML 5 proposed a block-level `a` tag. I don't even know where that ended :D

Comment: Jacub, I edited your code cause all those padding `left right top ...` are unnecessary.

Comment: @JakubMichálek in HTML5 you can wrap a block level element inside `anchor`. They never said that `a` tag will ever be a `block` level element by default. You can always set it as `display:block;` manually, but the rule for nesting UL, OL elements is really precise. No other elements allowed but `LI`

Answer (score 1):

> But I can not have both inline and block as display in css

There is a way to have an element placed as an inline element and that behaves as a block element: 
`display: inline-block`

Comment: Please be more precise giving answers. And if the answer is `maybe`, maybe it's better suited as comment rather than Answer (`inline-block` is fine, but as it stands in your A. it has other know issues in the meanings of XBrowser compatib.)